# SSIS Teradata connection not appearing when creating new connection manager

Tags: ssis, teradata, tpt

I have Visual Studio 2019 and a SSIS Solution.

I have a current TPT Connection but it is showing an error. I need to create a TPT Connection to Terradata and I have installed the Attunity files and SSIS connector.

However Teradata does not appear in my list of available connections.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything. I have tried restarting SSIS.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you targeting? You may need the newer Microsoft connector rather than the old Attunity connector. Check the Microsoft documentation. You also need a version of TTU (TPTAPI) that is compatible with the specific SSIS connector you are using.